# Warning emscripten about environment variable NODE to replace with EM_NODE_JS

Tags: emscripten

Since I upgraded to emscripten 2.0.25 I get this warning during the compilation:

> warning: honoring legacy environment variable `NODE`.  Please switch to using `EM_NODE_JS` instead`

I installed emscripten as explained in [the doc](https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/downloads.html) by cloning their git repo. And did not set any variable myself.

Where is this `NODE` variable set? How can I switch to `EM_NODE_JS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in emscripten 2.0.30.

Project issue: https://github.com/emscripten-core/emsdk/issues/862